# a wooden thing used as a bed and a bench

Tags: vocabulary

What do we call the thing in the image?

[image]

In Asia, it is used for sitting and sleeping.

I'm not sure if it is found in English-speaking countries.

Comment: It's bed........

Comment: I certainly do not recognise it as a bed, and my heart goes out to anyone who has to sleep on one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recognise the piece of furniture having travelled in Asia many times. Since, at least in the UK, we would not normally sit or sleep on furniture like this, we do not have a specific word for it. Therefore, the word for it would depend on the context in which it was used. Most likely it would simply be called by the name of the use it had at the time. For instance, I have seen it referenced in novels set in India as simply ‘bed’, when used for sleeping. Likewise, when someone sits on it, it might be referred to as a ‘low bench’. However, it might simply be referred to using the word from the language of the setting of the novel.